# How to run a text file in resources folder as an argument?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have some code like this

```
object Long {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val reads = readFastaFile(args(0)).map(_._2).toSet
    println(assemble(reads))
}
```

I'm trying to take the file in resources folder on a command line.
Using Intellij, I changed the configuration so that program argument takes a file in the resources folder, "/dataset.txt".

When I change the code to

```
val reads = readFile("/25Dataset.txt").map(_._2).toSet
```

It seems to locate the file correctly, and compiles correctly.
Just not when I change to the argument in the command line.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `/dataset.txt` is an absolute path pointing to a file in system root, try removing the `/`. And what's the error you're seeing? Plus - the working example is using an entirely different filename (`/25Dataset.txt`) - do both files exist?